# Infimum of sum of three terms

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $b \in \mathbb{R}$ a constant  and $f,g : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I found the following statement in some notes and I cannot understand how they conclude it :
\begin{equation}
\inf \limits_{x \in X} \{f(x) + g(x) + b\} = \inf \limits_{x \in X} \{f(x) + b\} + \inf \limits_{x \in X} \{f(x) + g(x) \} 
\end{equation}
Is this possible ?
Could someone give me some help ?

Comment: "Some notes" could be wrong, but this statement is just **so** wrong that I suspect you're either misquoting or leaving out something very important.

Comment: it must be the second one.. i will look for the thing i am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true in general. For example, take $f (x)=1$ and $g (x)=-1$.